# Android layout: Some ViewPager fragments shall be covered by AppBar and some shall be below the AppBar

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a layout that contains an AppBarLayout with a Toolbar and TabLayout. Below that is a ViewPager that will show one of my fragments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:title="Titel">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/InfoViewTabs"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorTabNotSelected"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorTabSelected"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Due to `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`, the content of the view pager is below the toolbar (A). When I remove that behavior the ViewPager stretches over the complete layout and the AppBar will cover a part of it (B).
[image]
Normally I want behavior A, so the content of the ViewPagers fragment is fully visible. But now I have a fragment that shall be shown fullscreen (B) because the AppBar fades away via `OnPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled`.

My idea is to remove the behavior so the ViewPager will always be in fullscreen (B), and then move the fragments down somehow. But I don't want to put a top margin in the xml of those fragments, because what value would I choose. It is not possible to add the scrollbehavior to sub children of the view.

How can this be accomplished?
An example for such a layout is WhatsApp. Normally the tab layout is shown, but when you swipe to the camera, the toolbar fades and the camera below is in fullscreen.